# How to get from my Delphi Application the Inno Setup Installer "progress status/ logs" using file "mapping / shared memory"

Tags: delphi, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to communicate Installer (builded with inno-setup) progress status with my delphi application.

I tried with FileMapping but without success.

Anyone else tried to do something like? Or have another approach?

iss code example:

```
  PAGE_READWRITE = 4;
  {$EXTERNALSYM PAGE_READWRITE}
  SECTION_QUERY = 1;
  {$EXTERNALSYM SECTION_QUERY}
  SECTION_MAP_WRITE = 2;
  {$EXTERNALSYM SECTION_MAP_WRITE}
  SECTION_MAP_READ = 4;
  {$EXTERNALSYM SECTION_MAP_READ}
  FILE_MAP_COPY = SECTION_QUERY;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FILE_MAP_COPY}
  FILE_MAP_WRITE = SECTION_MAP_WRITE;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FILE_MAP_WRITE}
  FILE_MAP_READ = SECTION_MAP_READ;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FILE_MAP_READ}


function CreateFileMapping(
  File: Cardinal; Attributes: Cardinal; Protect: Cardinal;
  MaximumSizeHigh: Cardinal; MaximumSizeLow: Cardinal; Name: PAnsiChar): Cardinal;
  external 'CreateFileMappingW@kernel32.dll stdcall';
  
function MapViewOfFile(
  FileMappingObject: THandle; DesiredAccess: Cardinal; FileOffsetHigh: Cardinal;
  FileOffsetLow: Cardinal; NumberOfBytesToMap: Cardinal): PChar;
  external 'MapViewOfFile@kernel32.dll stdcall';
```